# How to define optional fields in POJO when mapping to a native query result

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Some of the fields in my POJO class might not be present in the result I obtain from the native query. How do I set some of the fields in my POJO as optional?

Below is my POJOCLass

```
public class GetTrucksDueResultModel 
{

private String drvr_id;

private String reg_id;

private Integer DRIVERS;

private String NEXT_DT;

public GetTrucksDueResultModel()
{

}

public GetTrucksDueResultModel(String drvr_id,String reg_id,String NEXT_DT,Integer DRIVERS)
{
    this.drvr_id = drvr_id.trim();
    this.reg_id = reg_id.trim();
    this.NEXT_DT = NEXT_DT;
    this.DRIVERS = DRIVERS;
}
public Integer getDrivers() {
    return DRIVERS;
}

public void setDrivers(Integer dRIVERS) {
    DRIVERS = dRIVERS;
}

public String getNEXT_DT() {
    return NEXT_DT;
}

public void setNEXT_DT(String nEXT_DT) {
    NEXT_DT = nEXT_DT;
}

public String getDrvr_id() {
    return drvr_id;
}

public void setDrvr_id(String drvr_id) {
    this.drvr_id = drvr_id;
}

public String getReg_id() {
    return reg_id;
}

public void setReg_id(String reg_id) {
    this.reg_id = reg_id;
}

}
```

Below is my sqlMapping

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="GetTrucksDueResultMapping",
classes={
@ConstructorResult(targetClass=GetTrucksDueResultModel.class,
    columns={
        @ColumnResult(name="drvr_id", type=String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name="reg_id", type=String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name="NEXT_DT", type=String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name="DRIVERS", type=Integer.class)

    })
}
)
```

My query looks like this

```
String querySelectPart="Select DRIVERS";
    if(flag==true)
    {
        querySelectPart="Select drvr_id, reg_id, NEXT_DT, DRIVERS ";

    }
Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(querySelectPart + '...some complex query..',"GetTrucksDueResultMapping")
List<GetTrucksDueResultModel> result= nativeQuery.getResultList();
```

Below is the complete error I'm getting when "flag" is false(i.e I'm Selecting only DRIVERS field)

```
2020-05-12 13:13:50.325 ERROR 22492 --- [nio-8083-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not resolve column name in result set [drvr_id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not resolve column name in result set [drvr_id]] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: S0022: Invalid column name 'drvr_id'.
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(ErrorMessage.java:752) ~[jconn4.jar:JDK 1.6/jdbcmain/Sun Jan 12 09:45:05 PST 2014]
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.TdsResultSet.findColumnByLabel(TdsResultSet.java:738) ~[jconn4.jar:JDK 1.6/jdbcmain/Sun Jan 12 09:45:05 PST 2014]
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybResultSet.findColumn(SybResultSet.java:1186) ~[jconn4.jar:JDK 1.6/jdbcmain/Sun Jan 12 09:45:05 PST 2014]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.findColumn(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:?]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.JdbcResultMetadata.resolveColumnPosition(JdbcResultMetadata.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:482) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:2214) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2170) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1931) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:938) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2161) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1016) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at com.manh.optimizationportal.TrucksDue.TrucksDueRepository.GetSpecificTrucksDue(TrucksDueRepository.java:55) ~[classes/:?]
at com.manh.optimizationportal.TrucksDue.TrucksDueRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$207bd2da.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at com.manh.optimizationportal.TrucksDue.TrucksDueRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$854457a7.GetSpecificTrucksDue(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
at com.manh.optimizationportal.TrucksDue.TrucksDueService.getSpecificTrucksDue(TrucksDueService.java:38) ~[classes/:?]
at com.manh.optimizationportal.TrucksDue.TrucksDueController.getSpecificTrucksDue(TrucksDueController.java:35) ~[classes/:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_144]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]
```

Comment: @Simon Martinelli I believe you can answer this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Ady Junior please try to answer this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different SqlResultSetMapping when your flag is false.
Something like the one below

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="GetTrucksDueResultMapping",
classes={
@ConstructorResult(targetClass=GetTrucksDueResultModel.class,
    columns={
        @ColumnResult(name="DRIVERS", type=Integer.class)

    })
})
```

And a new constructor to your class

```
public GetTrucksDueResultModel(T,Integer DRIVERS)
{
    this.drvr_id = "";
    this.reg_id = "";
    this.NEXT_DT = "";
    this.DRIVERS = DRIVERS;
}
```

Comment: I have to again write a new constructor If mapping alone changes. Also a new POJO class. Below is my error when I tried to change only the mapping "Could not locate appropriate constructor on class : GetTrucksDueResultModel; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate appropriate constructor on class : GetTrucksDueResultModel"

Comment: If you add a constructor with a single argument, that adds a value for DRIVERS and nulls the other 3 this may solve this issue. As the error suggests it is only looking for a constructor, not an entire new class.

Comment: Working. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, please mark as the answer and upvote it.